# Cocoa Object Idle Timer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to understand the best way to invalidate an object based on a specified idle time. I have a joystick object that when instantiated from the joystickAdded method below, automatically starts up an NSTimer for that instance:

Joystick

```
idleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300 target:self selector:@selector(invalidate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

This works fine, but my joysticks array doesnt get cleaned up because the method that should be called when idle is joystickRemoved, but I have no idea how to call this, or if NSTimer is the best way for this.

JoystickController

```
void joystickAdded(void *inContext, IOReturn inResult, void *inSender, IOHIDDeviceRef device) {
    JoystickController *self = (__bridge JoystickController*)inContext;
    IOHIDDeviceOpen(device, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);

    // Filter events for joystickAction
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kIOHIDElementTypeInput_Button] forKey:(NSString*)CFSTR(kIOHIDElementTypeKey)];
    IOHIDDeviceSetInputValueMatching(device, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(dict));

    // Register callback for action event to find the joystick easier
    IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputValueCallback(device, joystickAction, (__bridge void*)self);
    Joystick *js = [[Joystick alloc] initWithDevice:device];
    [[self joysticks] addObject:js];
}

void joystickRemoved(void *inContext, IOReturn inResult, void *inSender, IOHIDDeviceRef device) {
    // Find joystick
    JoystickController *self = (__bridge JoystickController*)inContext;
    Joystick *js = [self findJoystickByRef:device];

    if(!js) {
        NSLog(@"Warning: No joysticks to remove");
        return;
    }

    [[self joysticks] removeObject:js];
    [js invalidate];
}

void joystickAction(void *inContext, IOReturn inResult, void *inSender, IOHIDValueRef value) {
    long buttonState;

    // Find joystick
    JoystickController *self = (__bridge JoystickController*)inContext;
    IOHIDDeviceRef device = IOHIDQueueGetDevice((IOHIDQueueRef) inSender);
    Joystick *js = [self findJoystickByRef:device];

    // Get button state
    buttonState = IOHIDValueGetIntegerValue(value);

    switch (buttonState) {
        // Button pressed
        case 1: {
            // Reset joystick idle timer
            [[js idleTimer] setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:300]];
            break;
        }
        // Button released
        case 0:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `NSTimer` will be calling `invalidate` on your `JoystickController`. Where is that method?

Comment: `invalidate` is in the Joystick class, hence, `[js invalidate]`

Comment: Ah the timer is in `Joystick` not the controller, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a delegate pattern.

1) Make a protocol `JoystickDelegate`, declare the method `- (void)joystickInvalidated:(Joystick *)joystick`.

2) `JoystickController` should then implement `JoystickDelegate`. Implement the method to remove `joystick` from your array.

3) Finally make a weak property called `delegate` in the `Joystick` interface and on every init of `Joystick` in `joystickAdded` assign `self` on `js.delegate`.

4) Now whenever `invalidate` is called, just call the `delegate` with `self` inside `Joystick`:

```
[self.delegate joystickInvalidated:self];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response :)

Although this works, I do have an exception if a joystick is now manually removed from Bluetooth:

`- (void)invalidate {
    // Remove joystick from joysticks array
    [self.delegate removeFromJoysticks:self];

    IOHIDDeviceClose(device, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
    NSLog(@"Removed HID device: %@", productName);

    if (bluetoothDevice) {
        [bluetoothDevice closeConnection];
        NSLog(@"Removed Bluetooth device: %@", [bluetoothDevice nameOrAddress]);
    }
}`

IOHIDDeviceClose: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Comment: Seems the timer was causing this, I had to use `[idleTimer invalidate]` in the `invalidate` method within `Joystick`, since the timer still had potential to fire if the joystick was removed manually...thank you for the help :D